# I share my psn account with my friend and want to get it back without getting banned

Tags: psn

I shared my games with my friend and my account is primary on his ps4 and i cant play offline anymore on my ps4 i want to know what will happen if i active my account on my ps4? Will he get banned or just the games will be locked for him?

Answer (score 1):

He will be locked out of the games. But to do this you will need to deactivate his PS4 as your primary device. You can do this by either going into the settings on his PS4 and deactivating your profile from his PS4 or you can do it remotely via the [account management website](http://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/). Once you've deactivated his system you can activate yours as the Primary.